# Mysql unable to update a row, when multiple selects are in process or taking too much time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called Settings which has only one row. The settings are very important in all the cases for my program, The Settings is been read by 200 to 300 users every second. I haven't used any caching yet. I cannot update the settings table for a value like Limit. Change the limit from 5 -10 Or anything from an API.
Ex: Limit Products 5 - 10. The update query runs forever.
 From the Workbench, I can update the record, But from Admin Panel through API it's not updating or take too much time.  Table - **InnoDB**

```
1. Already Tried Locking With Read - Write. 
2. Transaction.
3. Made a View of the table and Tried to update the table, the Same Issue remains.
4. The Update query is fine from Workbench, But through an API. It runs all day.
```

Is there anyway, I can lock the read operations on the table and update the table. I have only one row in a table.

Any help would be highly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a really good use case for using [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html).

> The query cache stores the text of a SELECT statement together with the corresponding result that was sent to the client. If an identical statement is received later, the server retrieves the results from the query cache rather than parsing and executing the statement again. The query cache is shared among sessions, so a result set generated by one client can be sent in response to the same query issued by another client.
>
> The query cache can be useful in an environment where you have tables that do not change very often and for which the server receives many identical queries.

To enable the query cache, you can run:

```
SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 1000000;
```

And then edit your mysql config file (typically /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf):

```
query_cache_size=1000000
query_cache_type=2
query_cache_limit=100000
```

And then for your query you can change it to:

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE * FROM your_table;
```

And that should make it so you are able to update the table (as it won't be constantly locked).

You would need to restart the server.

As an alternative, you could implement cacheing in your PHP application.  I would use something like memcached, but as a very simplistic solution you could do something like:

```
$settings = json_decode(file_get_contents("/path/to/settings.json"), true);
$minute = intval(date('i'));
if (isset($settings['minute']) && $settings['minute'] !== $minute) {
    $settings = get_settings_from_mysql();
    $settings['minute'] = intval(date('i'));
    file_put_contents("/path/to/settings.json", json_encode($settings), LOCK_EX);
}
```

Comment: Haven't tried caching the result, Require a super privileged for running the query, I ll try to implement and get back soon. @dave

Comment: HI @dave, do i need to restart the server to enable query caching because already users are interacting with the application. I have configured as per above suggested from the google console, Can't able to notice any difference, am i missing something. Please revert.

Comment: Hi @dave, I had managed to do it through caching the result in memcached. I was able to update the table and overwrite the data in memcahed too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Are the queries being run in the context of transactions with say a transaction isolation level for repeatable read?  It sounds like the update isn't able to complete due to a lock on the table, in which case caching isn't likely to be able to help you, as on a write the cache will be purged.  More information on repeatable reads can be found at https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/08/28/differences-between-read-committed-and-repeatable-read-transaction-isolation-levels/.

Comment: He isn't able to write because a table can have multiple read locks simultaneously.  Since he has 200-300 users every second, the read lock never gets released.  I'm unclear on why caching wouldn't help here - the cache means the table generally won't be locked, so he can make a write, and on a write, the cache would be purged, so clients will then get the new value, which will then recreate the cache, again preventing the table from being locked.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Honestly, this boils down to the implementation details of the cache in the database, which I don't know MySQL well enough to answer.  This is the type of thing i would try to avoid, where an application would only work if caching was in use, even if it DID work.  In looking back at the original question, the fact that "4. The Update query is fine from Workbench, But through an API. It runs all day." seems to indicate to me it isn't an inherent lock, but the context of the reads and writes through the API that is causing the issue, which why I was asking about the transaction isolation levels.

Comment: @Erik Brandsberg, highly appreciate for helping me out. I have already tried all the above Including Dave's suggestion on Caching. As you said there might be a read and write lock through API call. Even Select for update takes lot of time. Let me go through the link and find out any way to deal with this situation, as this table has only one row and is been locked which is holding the update process delay.

Comment: I do have a fairly easy way to debug this--can you contact me at erik(at)heimdalldata.com?  It will be using a product that I develop, but I promise this is just to help debug your issue, and won't be a sales pitch.

Comment: Hi @Erik Brandsberg, I wasn't aware of caching methods. I had managed to do it through caching the result in memcached. I was able to update the table and overwrite the data in memcahed too . I would definitely ping you . Thank you very much.